secure_file_priv error is raised even when using that folder
I'm trying to run the following :
SET @tt = CONCAT(
    "SELECT * FROM my_table INTO OUTFILE '", 
    CONCAT(@@global.secure_file_priv, 'my_table.csv'), 
    "' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
);

PREPARE stmt FROM @tt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

But run into the following :
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
But I'm explicitely using the folder given but the secure_file_priv variable. What am I doing wrong ?

Does the directory name in secure_file_priv end with a /? If not, you need to include it in the concatenation.

Execute SELECT @tt; instead of PREPARE/EXECUTE/DROP and look at the query text. Maybe you need in additional REPLACE(@@global.secure_file_priv, '\\', '/')?
